# PHP header - adding different metatags per page

Tags: php, header, include, meta-tags

I have a commom php header. I would like to add page specific META.

Currently my header looks like this.

```
<?php include ('includes/pageheader.php'); ?>
```

It currently uses a long if statemment

```
<?php $page =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if($page == "/") {
  ?>
<!-- Metadata for home -->
?>
```

I was wondering if there was a better way or a class to be able to build up page specific meta to this header.

Comment: Try Switch case

Comment: If each of your routes/URI's is stored in a database, you can look up each pages metadata based on the request.

Comment: if you can create header files like homeheader.php , mypage1.php, my page2.php, & if you can identify the exact page, you can use : <?php include ('includes/'.$page.'.php'); ?>  you can avoid lots of if else statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header, you could do something like this.

```
<?php if(isset($header)): ?>
  <?php foreach($header as $tag): ?>
    <?= $tag ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Then above your include, you could add.

```
<?php
$header[] = '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
$header[] = '<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">';
$header[] = '<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">';
$header[] = '<meta name="author" content="John Doe">';
$header[] = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">';
include ('includes/pageheader.php');
?>
```